# Disabling time synchronization with Hyper-V

Tags: windows, hyper-v, date-time

I found that when attempting to change the Date/Time settings on a Hyper-V virtualised Windows 8 OS, I found that the date would immediately change back to the correct date.

How can I prevent the Date/Time from reverting once I've set it?

Comment: With PowerShell:: `Disable-VMIntegrationService –Name <Service Name> -VMName <Target Guest VM Name>`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open the 'Hyper-V Manager' application on the host machine.

On the list of 'Virtual Machines', right-click on the VM where you want to change the Date/Time settings and click 'Settings'.

Under the 'Management' section of options, select 'Integration Services', and uncheck the 'Time synchronization' option.

[image]

When changing the Date/Time settings from within the VM, the Date/Time will no longer revert to the Date/Time on your host machine.

Comment: You might want to include the warning that time keeping in VM's without this can be very iffy....

Answer (score 0):

I found Virtualbox the most easy:
https://tothecore.sk/2021/04/08/disable-time-sync-for-virtualbox-virtual-machines/

How to prevent time from Host:

Close running VM
run cmd as admin.
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBOXManage.exe list vms
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe setextradata "Win7x64_" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
I normally do this:

If you have multiple VMs then:
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBOXManage.exe list vms
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe setextradata "042feed8-3612-4aa0-b840-727b39771ed5" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to temporarily disable time synchronization for hyper-v vm's however every hour or so the OS will sync with the hardware clock aka the bios time. As far as i known its not possible to change the bios time for hyper-v vm's. if you disable the windows time service, the hyper-v time service and task scheduler time synchronization jobs, the OS will sync the system time to the bios clock roughly every hour.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/access-bios-settings-system-date-for-vm-in-hyper-v/62f4ea6b-7bdb-433b-83d3-3fd03fd4978a

I ended up just creating a virtualbox vm and using the bios time offset command
https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-set-the-bios-date-in-virtualbox/

hopefully this feature will be implemented in the future for hyper-v.